Moving from reactor 3.5 to 3.6 in Spring flux shows large increase in cpu due to context propagation. Can this be avoided?
When switching from reactor 3.5 to 3.6 we noticed a large increase in CPU usage.
Under same load (around 200 req per sec) the CPU usage doubles (~30% to ~60% avg with spikes to 100%).
Using profiling we see a big increase in calls to copy context for context propagation.
Slf4j is used for logging with (ThreadLocal) MDC for trace ids and application specific ids.
We use automatic context propagation via Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation()
Some numbers for startup and first call.
reactor-core 3.5.18/reactor-core-micrometer 1.0.7 (reactor bom 2022.0.20)
brave.baggage.CorrelationScopeDecorator$Multiple#decorateScope is called 286 times
Flux.ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber#onNext() 16 times
Mono.ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber#onNext() 31 times

reactor-core 3.6.7/reactor-core-micrometer 1.0.18 (reactor bom 2023.0.2)
brave.baggage.CorrelationScopeDecorator$Multiple#decorateScope is called 649 times
Flux.ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber#onNext() 108 times
Mono.ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber#onNext() 32 times

So more calls from FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.onNext() and even more calls to decorateScope.
In the past we saw managed to reduce CPU usage with ~30% using the "decorate on last" setting of Spring Sleuth. For Reactor 3.6 is there a way to decrease the number of needed calls?
Make minimal changes and be able to upgrade to new Spring Boot/Cloud and reactor without the large increase of CPU usage and with keeping the context propagation where needed.
There is enough context propagation with 3.5, so the extra overhead in 3.6 does not bring extra needed propagation in our case.
Looking at the traces, many copies are being made, while the "flux" stays same thread.
Here is a project that shows the increase of calls plus some stacktrace information of where the calls are from using Byteman. You can easily switch from reactor 3.5 to reactor 3.6 using maven profiles reactor35 and reactor36.
https://github.com/stokpop/reactive-tracing-issue
A simple case is used together with ContextRegistry...registerThreadLocalAccessor. We count the number of calls made to MDC.put. You can see an increase in calls from 27 to 135 by just switching release.
Example of a partial stacktrace captured by Byteman:
[BYTEMAN] org.slf4j.MDC#put(requestId) in thread HttpClient-1-Worker-0
org.slf4j.MDC.put(MDC.java:128)
nl.stokpop.performance.reactive.ReactiveDemoStandAlone._init_$lambda$9(ReactiveDemoStandAlone.kt:36)
io.micrometer.context.ContextRegistry$1.setValue(ContextRegistry.java:121)
io.micrometer.context.DefaultContextSnapshot.setThreadLocal(DefaultContextSnapshot.java:102)
io.micrometer.context.DefaultContextSnapshotFactory.setAllThreadLocalsFrom(DefaultContextSnapshotFactory.java:125)
io.micrometer.context.DefaultContextSnapshotFactory.setThreadLocalsFrom(DefaultContextSnapshotFactory.java:109)
reactor.core.publisher.ContextPropagation.setThreadLocals(ContextPropagation.java:85)
reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:117)
org.reactivestreams.FlowAdapters$FlowToReactiveSubscriber.onNext(FlowAdapters.java:211)

(In our complete app there is brave CorrelationScopeDecorator.Multiple#decorateScope, which might be somewhat more heavy, but the number of calls seem to increase in similar amounts going from 3.5 to 3.6.)
This blocks us from going to higher releases. We are using spring boot 3.1.12, spring cloud 2022.0.5 and reactor-bom 2022.0.20.
(P.S. Not sure if this is a "regression bug" so posting this question. Would it make sense to create a regression issue on the Github reactor-core project?)

I think it's an issue to submit to Github

Could you please try:

Do not define versions that are managed by Boot (context-propagation, reactor-bom)
Letting auto-context propagation do its job (context registry, setting mdc, etc.)
Java (to exclude differences with Kotlin)
Upgrade to Boot 3.3


Just hit the same problem with ~25-30% overhead. hopefully it is resolved soon.
https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3840
